# AngularJS application minification protection

Tags: angularjs

I am having a problem that maybe someone can guide me to solve it. I have an angularjs app that I am minifying to get a production distribution.

Like the documentation says [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) I can use $inject keyword to avoid Dependency injection problems.

After the minification process, I am now having the following [error](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a) 
but since the code was minified I am unable to find out what component (service/directive/etc) I missed to protect against minification.

is there a simple way to find out the source of the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no simple way to do it. However, there are more solutions to this particular problem than using the `$injector` service.

- Use [ngmin task](https://github.com/btford/grunt-ngmin) before minification. It searches for all problematic occurrences and replaces them with minify-friendly code.
- Do what ngmin does manually. That is wherever you have such declaration:

`...(function ($scope, service1) {})`

replace it with

```
(['$scope', 'service1',
    function ($scope, service1) {})
```

We had the same problem in our projects and we decided to go with the minify-friendly code (second solution). Though today I'd probably give ngmin at least a try - it's stable enough now.

Comment: Hi Miszy, I found the problem. Indeed I was already using the ngmin task that do the work for of protecting against minification. But I found out that in one of my routes, I use a "resolve" funcion that depends on a service and for this specific case the ngmin task does not convert the code. Thanks to guide me to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you use [ character in the same line, you can try to grep in your source files and grep -v to [ character.

Like this:

```
grep function $(find . -name '*.js') |grep -v -e '\['
```

Or you can try to generate sourcemaps to help your browser to find the real source.