# How to test minified code. Is it even necessary

Tags: javascript, jestjs, minify, terser

I am wondering if I can test my code after it was minified. Is it even the right concept? Currently I am testing my code with `jest` then minify it using `terser`. But what if something goes wrong in the process. Or am I overcomplicating things and should not worry about that?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems a reasonable concern.  Why not simply minify before testing?  That's closer to testing what you'll use in production anyway.  You might want a separate task if you need to debug through your test-cases, but that's not hard to set up.

Comment: By trial and error. Large js frameworks like angularjs have built in protection for minification https://stackoverflow.com/a/22684147/10634638

Comment: I'd personally prefer to trust my minifier works correctly. If it doesn't...then why would I bother using it if I'm going to second-guess it every single time it does stuff? Check what users of the minification library have to say, check their bug tracker, try to judge the maturity of the project, pick a stable release and work with that. At most, you can run your unit tests before and after minification but I wouldn't make that part of the whole automated process. It's enough to execute manually occasionally or something.

Comment: @VLAZ: It's an interesting call.  My question is whether there a real reason to run the test suite through the unminified code?  Obviously this is different for real-time tests of the current module, which need to be as fast as possible, but for the whole suite, don't we want to test what we're actually supplying to production?

Comment: @ScottSauyet "*whether there a real reason to run the test suite through the unminified code?*" I'd say yes. The tests are not there to test if your code works after minification but whether or not the code *works*. My philosophy is to make the tests as simple as possible, not simpler. The fewer things that can fail the better - you have less to investigate to fix them. If a test fails when running against minified resource, did it fail because the minification was wrong or the behaviour was wrong? So, if you want to test functionality, you ideally want to know if the functionality works -

Comment: @ScottSauyet testing if the minifcation preserves the behaviour is a *separate* concern to that. Ideally, merits a different test. However, if you doubt it, then why minify? Should we also test the SASS compilation? Should we double-check if each library runs the way we want it to and write tests for jQuery or whatever? What about dependencies of libraries? At some point we *have* to just accept *something* works, or else it's an endless spiral of uncertainty and doubt. That's why I'd prefer to assume the tool I've chosen for some task is capable of doing that task.

Comment: @VLAZ: In practice, I do that a lot. But on at least three separate projects, there were problems caused by minification that ended up with us testing post-minification, either as well as or instead of pre-minification. I do see a difference from SASS or other tools, in that what we're testing is our own code. We need to decide if what we're testing is the code that we write or the code that we deliver, and I don't think that's a simple call. It also matters whether minification is separate from bundling; if it's all one and the same, then the test imports have to change, and its much larger.